# In-app pruchase not working but getting product response

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, rmstore

I know there are LOTS of these questions but I can't find one that helps.

I've implemented IAP many times but not in the last year. Things seem to have changed. I created my IAP items in iTunes Connect and their status is now 'Waiting for review'. I'm using a library called RMStore to make IAP easier.

When I make a call to purchase with the product ID I get an 'invalid product ID error'. Do my IAP items have to pass review BEFORE I can test them?

Edit:

I did some more testing. Even though I get invalid product ID when I try to make a purchase I am able to get the details of the products fine with the same product ID's.

This is the code I call when I get the error.

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] addPayment:productID success:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
        } failure:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction, NSError *error) {
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RMStore author here.

> When I make a call to purchase with the product ID I get an 'invalid product ID error'. Do my IAP items have to pass review BEFORE I can test them?

No.

> I did some more testing. Even though I get invalid product ID when I try to make a purchase I am able to get the details of the products fine with the same product ID's.

Before purchasing products you need to request their details. If you fail to do so, RMStore will log "unknown product id" in DEBUG.

It might help to post the exact error message.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The exact error is: Something went wrong: Error Domain=net.robotmedia.store Code=100 "Unknown product identifier" UserInfo=0x17d45160 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown product identifier}. I'll add the code to the question.

Comment: Requesting the products before purchasing fixed the problem. Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: It's how StoreKit works. I suggest reading the documentation.

Comment: I previously used MKStoreKit for IAP and don't remember having to do this. I'll take a look at the docs though as I haven't used StoreKit in quite a while. Thanks for your work on RMStore!

Comment: To clarify, the documentation for RMStore states that you "just" need to do that one step. Issue to update the documentation is at https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/issues/152